# Where do I find logs for x2go windows client?

Tags: x2go, x2goclient

I am tring to connect from Windows x2go client to linux server with x2go, black window splashes and goes away, I can't catch the error message. Where can I find a log file?

Answer (score -1):

Was about to answer on your other question but it's now closed.

There's no dedicated x2go log file. This is because x2go server uses SSH (that's the answer I was given when I had to troubleshoot my X2Go).

You can still browse `/var/log/auth.log` and there you should be able to find why you're thrown out.